# Reload / Refresh java class after writing

Tags: java, junit, refresh

Is there a way in which a unit class can be refreshed / reloaded during runtime ? 
I am writing new tests to the class depending on the number of iterations, however, when executing using JUnitCore, the unit class is not being updated. For the tests to update I would need to refresh the project manually, however, this will not work for my project.

Could you kindly point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should provide some example code; as I really don't understand that you mean that you write "new tests depending on the number of iterations". And just for the sake of it: normally unit tests are expected to **only** tests small units; and therefore a unit test run should be really really quick. If your unit tests run so long that you can update the source in the mean time ... that sounds like you are doing something wrong ...

Comment: The unit tests are short, I am adding new tests on every iteration depending on the coverage obtained. For example, I first write a test with input value 1, if coverage is lower than 50%, then add test with input value 2. My question is, is there a way by which I can update a single .java file or the whole project during runtime execution. As after each added test I need to re-calculate the coverage and without refreshing the file it will keep in memory the old value.

Comment: Ah, OK; now I get it. Then I can't help; I am running my unit tests in eclipse; and there I just press the run button, and it will run the latest version. Not sure why JUnitCore behaves differently.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Probably you should try to provide a minimal, working example that people could run locally to repro your problem. Besides, pulling together such an example has a good chance ... that while doing so, you figure what is broken in your setup. Happened more than once to me ;-)